# PhpStorm says: Please select local PHP Interpreter to use built-in web server

Tags: phpstorm

I am using `remote php interpreter` in PhpStorm.

When I try to run a php page called `phptest.php` with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, it says `Please select local PHP Interpreter to use built-in web server`

[image]

and the chromium opens `http://localhost:63342/.public_html/phptest.php` saying bad gateway.

So how to resolve this? I don't want to use local php interpreter because LAMP is already installed in the remote server.

following are the snapshots of remote php interpreter and the errot message:
[image: remote php interpreter configuration]

Comment: You can configure phpstorm to use remote php interpreter instead of local php interpreter. [Configure PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-remote-php-interpreters.html)

Comment: I did that also. I used both, but still it shows 502 bad gateway.

Comment: are you sure that your localhost:63342 target your remote server ?

Comment: how to know that. i try localhost it shows the root directory of the remote server

Comment: Screenshots please (your Run/Debug Configuration that you are trying to use). Right now you are trying to open your file locally and therefore that message makes perfect sense. If you have "LAMP already installed on remote server" then use it instead of local one. You can find tutorials and how-tos here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials

Comment: If you're configured PHPStorm with ssh/sftp, then first check whether you are able to connect to remote ssh/sftp server or not. For ssh you can check with putty. If you're able to connect then check whether /usr/bin/php is accessible or not and the same path is configure in your PHPStorm

Comment: i am able to ssh. Note its a contianer. From contianey i can ssh to host. but both share the ports. Other than php i can open all html files. they dont show any such error

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi *"Other than php i can open all html files. they dont show any such error "* What URLs are used in such case?

Comment: example i have a file 1.html and open it in phpstorm. then i click the chromium icon it shows the url as http://localhost:63342/1.html

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi That means that this file was served by PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server (a local URL as you can see). It is the same server as in your PHP files case .. just to process PHP file the local PHP interpreter is required. So .. if you have your own web server (Apache/nginx/whatever) -- use it instead of PhpStorm's one. Just define deployment entry and provide URL there.

Comment: I have the local php interpreter also. I even used that, it still shows the error bad gateway. I can use the deployment thing, Its good, if i have same starting url, like index.php. but if i have lots of php files which i want to check individually, i have to create so many deplayments

Comment: i try this 
`$ php -S localhost:54545 phptest.php; Output --
PHP 5.6.14 Development Server started at Mon Jan 25 17:45:18 2016;
Listening on http://localhost:54545;
Document root is /home/simha/.public_html;
Press Ctrl-C to quit.; `

then in chromium i open http://localhost:54545. it says waiting for localhost

Comment: @ Santhosh Yedidi, i have remote php interpreter only. But i configured in PHPstorm using SFTP. But cannt run local php using remote php interpreter.  Is it possible local php code can run using remote php interpreter? What was the solution you had?  plz help me to solve this.